# Align input and button on one line

Tags: html, css, haml, sass

I have such table part:

```
<td>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/line_items" method="post">
    <input class="qnt_to_cart2" id="110040Q" name="cart_quantity" pattern="0|[1-9]\d{0,2}" required="required" type="text" value="1">
    <input class="orange-button to-cart_no" id="110040Q" name="commit" type="submit" value="В корзину">
  </form>
</td>
```

And css (sass):

```
.qnt_to_cart, .qnt_to_cart2{
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}

.orange-button{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  @include gradient-background(bottom, $or1, #fbb752); 
  //background: url('button-carbon-bg.png') no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, $or1, #fbb752);
  @include border-radius(5px, 5px, 5px, 5px);
  //background: transparent url('button-carbon-bg.png') no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #d27d00;
  font-family: “Myriad Pro”, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: $or3;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .70);
  font-style: normal;
  @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5));
  border-bottom:2px solid #B16900;
}
```

[All css file is here](http://pastebin.com/9tTjUYmh)

Now i see this:

[image]

So how to layout two elements on one line, with minimum code transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/line_items" method="post">
      <input class="qnt_to_cart2" id="110040Q" name="cart_quantity" pattern="0|[1-9]\d{0,2}" required="required" type="text" value="1">
    </form>
  </td>

  <td align="right">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/line_items" method="post">
      <input class="orange-button to-cart_no" id="110040Q" name="commit" type="submit" value="В корзину">
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` to your CSS-classes.

That should do the trick, given that your `td` is wide enough of course.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the 2 elements don't have enough space to be side by side, which is causing the button to pass to the next line.

Try making the parent element a little wider.

**Edit**

Try adding a div like this.

```
<td>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/line_items" method="post">
    <div class="wrapper_test">
      <input class="qnt_to_cart2" id="110040Q" name="cart_quantity" pattern="0|[1-9]\d{0,2}" required="required" type="text" value="1">
      <input class="orange-button to-cart_no" id="110040Q" name="commit" type="submit" value="В корзину">
    </div>
  </form>
</td>
```

And add this to the *css*

```
.wrapper_test { width: 150px } /* or a little more if needed */
```

---

Alternatively, this.

```
<td>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/line_items" method="post">
    <table><tr><td>
      <input class="qnt_to_cart2" id="110040Q" name="cart_quantity" pattern="0|[1-9]\d{0,2}" required="required" type="text" value="1">
    </td><td>
      <input class="orange-button to-cart_no" id="110040Q" name="commit" type="submit" value="В корзину">
    </td></td></table>
  </form>
</td>
```

Comment: If there isn't anything limiting the width of the table, the button and textbox, should be side by side. I'll add an edit with another idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
display:inline-block;
```

you need this on both elements with

```
display:block;
```

on the parent element